# creation of several balls using JS does not work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a new balls from Ball function using `new Ball()` constructor. However, it is not working. My code below consists of `constructor` and a method `draw` that draws `ball` on canvas. Then in `init` function I am looping and creating 5 balls using that constructor and then calling `draw` function inside the loop. Then I am animating them using `setInterval`. But it somehow does not show balls on canvas.

Here is the code. How can I resolve this?

```
    function Ball (radius, color) {
        this.ballPosX = 0;
        this.ballPosY = 0;
        this.ballRadius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0; 
    }

    Ball.prototype.draw = function (context) {
      context.fillStyle = this.color;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(this.ballPosX, this.ballPosY, this.ballRadius, 0, 2*Math.PI,true);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
    };

    init();

    function init () {
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ball = new Ball(25, 'blue');
        ball.ballPosX = 50;
        ball.ballPosY = 75;
        ball.speedX = Math.random() * 5;
        ball.speedY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
        ball.draw(context);
        balls.push(ball);
      }
      setInterval(onEachStep, 1000/60);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the ball at every frame, not upon generation of the balls. Move the drawing call to the `onEachStep` function:

```
...
bal.ballPosX += ball.speedX; 
bal.ballPosY += ball.speedY;
...
bal.draw(context);
```

Then you don't need that global `ball` variable. Check the demo, I fixed a few things. Also, you should look into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) if you want smoother animations.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/t04xoxdq/1/